# Selenium, Robotframework - Error: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, appium, robotframework

I am using robotframework framework, using selenium and appium.
Recently I have been seing issues with chrome, I updated my chrome driver to 118v to match it with the current chrome version I am using. However, I still see the issue.

```
Exception trying to discover chromedriver version: error sending request for url (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json): error trying to connect: dns error: No such host is known. (os error 11001)

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
  (Session info: chrome=118.0.5993.71)
```

I was using selenium==`4.11.2`, however, I read somewhere that versions above `4.10` could cause problem, so I downgraded to selenium==`4.10.0`.

Please let me know if you need any information to resolve this issue.

Thank you

Help to fix this error on my code

Comment: How are you accessing the `chromedriver`? Via `SeleniumManager`? Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: Check my answer, see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

Sorry made a typo while updating the example address here. Just updated

Comment: post comment, its removing https://www automatically. but yes its updated already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome DevTools is supported now: v116, v117, and v118. Update your selenium version  to 4.14, see [the release notes](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/selenium-4-14-released/).

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.get("google.com")
```

Above is incorrect, `.get` method expects a fully qualified URL. Change the code as below:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```